# Java: Formatting issue. Grabbing unique characters from an array of strings and returning them

Tags: java

I'm having a problem getting the unique letters and digits out of an array of strings, and then returning them. I am having a formatting issue.

The given input is: `([abc, 123, efg])` and is supposed to return `abcefg123`,

however, mine returns: `abc123efg`

how can I fix this since `arrays.sort()` will end up putting the numbers first and not last?

Here is my method so far:

```
public static String getUniqueCharsAndDigits(String[] arr) {

    String str = String.join(",", arr);
    String myString = "";
    myString = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isLetterOrDigit((i))){
            if(myString.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                myString = myString + str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return myString;
}
```

Comment: What's your exact sorting logic? What should [a2b, 1c3] return?

Comment: What would happen if say an array entry has both letters and numbers, e.g. `def456` ?

Comment: from the tests I have ran, it would return a1b2c3

Comment: I am not sure how to get around having them both in the same array entry

Comment: This isn't a formatting issue -- is it? It's really an issue with lexicographic sort in Java, where you probably need to override it or use a custom sort method.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create two strings, one with the letters, one with the digits.

```
public static String getUniqueCharsAndDigits(String[] arr) {
    String str = String.join("", arr);
    String myLetters, myDigits;
    myLetters = myDigits = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(c)){
            if(myLetters.indexOf(c) == -1) {
                myLetters += c;
            }
        } else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            if(myDigits.indexOf(c) == -1) {
                myDigits += c;
            }
        }
    }
    //if they need to be sorted, sort each one individually here
    return myLetters + myDigits;
}
```

I've modified your code and deleted the unnecessary parts of it.